# How to solve AWS RDS issue: psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root"

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker

Im using terraform and have built the infrastructure below:

- VPC with Public subnets
- ECS Fargate and ECR
- Public RDS instance in the public subnets

I am using django as the backend framework.

Everything seem fine (docker compose logs report is fine and I can access AWS RDS via psql and RDS endpoint in the terminal) until the task of ECS start then stop immediately with the logs message:

> psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root"

here the logs from `docker-compose logs`

```
db          | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
db          | This user must also own the server process.
db          | 
db          | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
db          | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
db          | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
db          | 
db          | Data page checksums are disabled.
db          | 
db          | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
db          | creating subdirectories ... ok
db          | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
db          | selecting default max_connections ... 100
db          | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
db          | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
db          | creating configuration files ... ok
db          | running bootstrap script ... ok
db          | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
db          | syncing data to disk ... ok
db          | 
db          | 
db          | Success. You can now start the database server using:
db          | 
db          |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
db          | 
db          | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
db          | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
db          | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
db          | waiting for server to start....2021-08-08 16:34:32.374 UTC [48] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db          | 2021-08-08 16:34:32.375 UTC [48] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db          | 2021-08-08 16:34:32.382 UTC [49] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-08-08 16:34:31 UTC
db          | 2021-08-08 16:34:32.388 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db          |  done
db          | server started
db          | CREATE DATABASE
db          | 
db          | 
db          | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
db          | 
db          | 2021-08-08 16:34:32.842 UTC [48] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
db          | waiting for server to shut down....2021-08-08 16:34:32.844 UTC [48] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
db          | 2021-08-08 16:34:32.850 UTC [48] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 55) exited with exit code 1
db          | 2021-08-08 16:34:32.851 UTC [50] LOG:  shutting down
db          | 2021-08-08 16:34:32.886 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is shut down
db          |  done
db          | server stopped
db          | 
db          | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
db          | 
db          | 2021-08-08 16:34:33.008 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db          | 2021-08-08 16:34:33.008 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db          | 2021-08-08 16:34:33.008 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db          | 2021-08-08 16:34:33.012 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db          | 2021-08-08 16:34:33.017 UTC [76] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-08-08 16:34:32 UTC
db          | 2021-08-08 16:34:33.024 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

logs from `RDS`

```
2021-08-06 16:56:12 UTC:10.0.2.174(39934):root@testdb:[5710]:DETAIL:  Role "root" does not exist.
    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 13: "host   all             all         all         md5"
```

## Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /backend

COPY  requirements.txt /backend/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt && \
    pip install --upgrade pip


COPY . /backend/


COPY ./entrypoint.sh /

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

## entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

python manage.py migrate --no-input

python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

gunicorn backend.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I am not sure why this is happening.

Can someone please help me understand because locally PostgreSQL do not have any issue.

Comment: When you logged in with psql, did you do it for the database account named 'root'?

Comment: @jjanes no i logged in with the local user, i used the same credentials + user in settings.py for django and when i created the rds instance.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear.  Something must have gone wrong in creating or reading settings.py

Comment: Did you check the logfiles of postgresql? Do you need an entry in pg_hba.conf?

Comment: Best guess is some script is being run by the `root` user and it does not have a database user specified so it is falling back to the default of using the OS user name.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver @Steeeve @jjanes i have updated the logs from `docker-compose logs` not sure if trust could be the issue above

Comment: Please do not include images of textual information. Copy and paste the text and add to your question.  In any case the error is pretty straight forward; `root@testdb Role 'root' does not exist` (if I remember the error form correctly). Something is trying to log in as the `root` user. You will need to scan your setup for an explicit use of `root` or a case where you do not specify a user and the script is being run as the `root` user. FYI, this is Postgres not MySQL where a `root` user does exist, so is there maybe a migration error?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver image removed, also i have updated the post with the `entrypoint.sh` that does the migration for django

Comment: There is really much more I can say or do. The issue is clear cut, something is trying to connect as database user(role) `root` and no such user exists. You need to go through your code and grep for 'root'. Also look at the Postgres log to see if there is information just before the error that might help.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver believe me, i tried everyhing, scanned all the codes, i even tried to just use the console vs terraform, it work on the console, launching ecs fargate but where in the world am i doing something wrong in the codes

Comment: Best guess is you are not providing a database user name in a connection and you are running that connection as the `root` user. Check the Postgres logs and see what is happening just before the connection refusal.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thank you for pointing me to the right direction, to my future self..all you have to do is set the docker container as non root user...solved!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `root` database account with RDS databases. That is a reserved account that only Amazon has access to. You need to examine your RDS database configuration and figure out what your admin account name is.

Comment: thank you for pointing me to the right direction and to my future self..all you have to do is set the docker container as non root user...solved!

Comment: No! The docker container user should have no bearing at all on the DB account name being used, unless you aren't setting the DB account name correctly in your code.

Comment: it work now, as soon as I set the Dockerfile to non root, i can access the app from the browser which is served from AWS load balancer DNS 100% no problem