# how to use aws secret manager values of a postgres database in terraform ecs task definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have the `settings.py` file below of a django application using terraform , docker compose and im trying to get the value of the database stored in aws secret manager in ecs task definition

## settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": os.environ.get("POSTGRES_DB"),
        "USER": os.environ.get("POSTGRES_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("POSTGRES_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": os.environ.get("POSTGRES_HOST"),
        "PORT": 5432,
    }
}
```

## task definition

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "ecs_task_definition" {
  family                   = "ecs_container"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu                      = 256                      
  memory                   = 512
  execution_role_arn       = data.aws_iam_role.fargate.arn
  task_role_arn            = data.aws_iam_role.fargate.arn
  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      "name"         : "ecs_test_backend",
      "image"        : "${aws_ecr_repository.ecr_repository.repository_url}:latest",
      "cpu"          : 256,
      "memory"       : 512,
      "essential"    : true,
      "portMappings" : [
        {
          containerPort = 8000
        }
      ],
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/ecs_test_backend",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      }
      "environment"   : [
        {
          "name": "POSTGRES_DB",
          "value": "${var.POSTGRES_NAME}" <=== HERE
        },
        {
          "name": "POSTGRES_PASSWORD",
          "value": "${var.POSTGRES_PASSWORD}"  <=== HERE
        },
        {
          "name": "POSTGRES_USERNAME",
          "value": "${var.POSTGRES_USERNAME}"  <=== HERE
        },
        {
          "name": "POSTGRES_PORT",
          "value": "${var.POSTGRES_PORT}"  <=== HERE
        },
        {
          "name": "POSTGRES_HOST",
          "value": "${var.POSTGRES_HOST}"  <=== HERE
        },
      ]
    }
  ])
}
```

## variables

```
variable "POSTGRES_PASSWORD" {
    type = string
    default = "somepassword"
}
```

The variables above is the same used while creating the postgres rds instance.

The configuration below `var.XXX` does not seem to work as the task logs return `psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root"`

It probably because its not able to read the value.

Is the above the correct way to grab value from AWS Secret Manager using Terraform and ECS?

Comment: It would be easier to answer the question if you showed how you are setting the `var.POSTGRES_PASSWORD` and other environment variables. Ideally the code in your question should form a [mcve] that allows others to run it and see where it has the same error that you are getting.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I did update that variable its just a string

Comment: If the DB username `root` is getting into the container, then it sounds like you are setting the values correctly. Are you sure you are using the correct username/password? Where is the database running? Is it running on RDS?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the sensitive data handling feature of ECS tasks, documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data-secrets.html).

You would move the environment variables from the `environment` block of your task definition to the `secrets` block, and give the ARN of the secret instead of the value. The ECS container will then read those secrets when it starts your container, and set them in the container's environment.

Comment: Mark would you please give an example of what the codes would look like just for that section, did you mean each one secret per section or just a single ARN that would take care of all the env variables? I been blocked for a week now on this issue and I actually read that link before. (it would be very helpful thank you so much for your time)

Comment: @feldobadix Did this answer actually fix your problem? Your comment suggests not but you've marked it as accepted. An accepted answer should be that it definitely fixed your problem. If you wanted to reward/acknowledge a helpful answer then that should be an upvote (which you can do from 15 reputation onwards).

Comment: @MarkB I don't think this really answers the question. Yes, they should be using `secrets` to pass secrets such as the password to the task but it would still expose it as an environment variable so the way they are reading it in their application is correct and the issue is more about how `var.POSTGRES_PASSWORD` is set which you can't tell from the current state of the question.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR AWS documentation recommend to use `secrets` as @MarkB suggested but when u look at the console and what get passed in as env variable when the task is launched, its empty, reason why i asked him to give an example of the code. The above configuration do show the env variable but then a new error arise when the task is launched `postgres connection failed for user "root"`, I post the issue: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68688635/how-to-solve-aws-rds-issue-psycopg2-operationalerror-fatal-password-authentic. I been stucked for weeks on this and cant seem to find a solution

Comment: @ydaetskcoR ECS would read the secret value at runtime and inject it as a **container** environment variable. That is totally separate from the **local** environment variable thing happening in the original question. Local environment variables would no longer be needed.

Comment: That would be true if you knew he was passing the secret's ARN as the password and instead he needed to use `secrets` instead but you don't know that from what's in the current question because you don't know what they're passing into `var.POSTGRES_PASSWORD`.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I know for a fact he is NOT passing the secret ARN, and I specifically said in my answer that he should change to sending the secret ARN. The thing about using the ARN is that you can do that as a lookup entirely within Terraform, without having to pass anything in as a variable from outside Terraform, so again the local variables are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking and I couldn't find any good examples to achieve this in the proper way, and while the response from @Mark B adds some context is true that some code snippets can be helpful since sometimes is more complicated to code it (with all the requirements) than the theoretical explanation. With that said I will split into pieces what you need to complete:

**The parameter store**

You need to save your secrets somewhere and the parameters store is a good place for it according AWS best practices:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "main" {
  for_each    = var.parameters
  name        = "/path/${var.app_name}/${each.key}"
  description = "Secrets for application ${var.app_name}"
  type        = "SecureString"
  value       = each.value
}

variable "parameters" {
  type = map(any)
}

variable "app_name" {
  type = string
}

output "arns" {
  value = [for k, v in var.parameters : { name = k, valueFrom = aws_ssm_parameter.main[k].arn }]
}
```

(The code above creates several parameters)

Be sure of adding the correct permissions to your task execution role:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "parameter_policy" {
  name = "mypolicy"
  role = aws_iam_role.your_role.id

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = [
          "ssm:GetParameters",
        ]
        Effect   = "Allow"
        Resource = ["*"]
      },
    ]
  })
}
```

Be aware that the above is just an example, to follow best practices be sure to limit the resources to the arn(s) of the parameters created above.

**Finally how to use it**

```
container_definitions = <<TASK_DEFINITION
[
  {
    "name": "hello-world",
    "image": "nginxdemos/hello",
    "cpu": 1024,
    "memory": 2048,
    "essential": true,
    "secrets": ${jsonencode(module.hello-world-secrets.arns)},
    "logConfiguration": {
      "logDriver": "awslogs",
      "options": {
        "awslogs-region": "your_region",
        "awslogs-group": "hello_world",
        "awslogs-stream-prefix": "hello_world"
      }
    }
  }
]
TASK_DEFINITION
```

```
module "hello-world-secrets" {
  source   = "./modules/secrets"
  app_name = "hello-world"
  parameters = {
    hello = "world"
  }
}
```

You need to decide in which point create the secret / store the secret, e.g. on your CI/CD inject your secret and create the parameter store resource.

Hopefully, this help someone else looking for a way of achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

ECS Task definition in Teffaform following the AWS Well-Architected framework Security pillar and recommendations in ECS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html):

```
# main.tf

data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "postgres" {
  name = "postgres"
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "soar_api_task" {
... omitted
  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name         = var.service.name
      ... omitted
      environment = [
        { "name" : "TEST_ENV", "value" : var.test_env },
      ]
      secrets = [
        {"name": "DATABASE_HOST", "valueFrom": "${data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.postgres.arn}:host::"},
        {"name": "DATABASE_PORT", "valueFrom": "${data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.postgres.arn}:port::"},
        {"name": "DATABASE_USERNAME", "valueFrom": "${data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.postgres.arn}:username::"},
        {"name": "DATABASE_PASSWORD", "valueFrom": "${data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.postgres.arn}:password::"},
      ]
    }
  ])
}
```